# String's method, like MiddleIndexOf - can it be done?

Tags: c#, string

I know how to use string's method `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf`. But I'm wondering if is it somehow possible to do in a "short way" with some kind of "MiddleIndexOf", so something in between `IndexOf`, and `LastIndexOf`.

To tell you what I mean, Best way is to show an example:

```
string str = @"1\2\3\4\5";
```

How would it be possbile to get part of upper string from 4 on (so "4\5").
It means I cannot use IndexOf, or LastIndexOf, but I would need something like "BeforeLastIndexOf" method.

Or not just that, lets say I want part of string from 3 on (so "3\4\5"). This even means I cannot use "BeforeLastIndexOf", but something different.

--

This would mean: 1 before LastIndexOf, or 2 before LastIndexOf (or maybe from front: 2 after IndexOf, or 3 after IndexOf).

--

I know I can split string by backslash delimiter, but I would like to know if there is any way to use a string methods (like explained).

Big thx in advance,

bye

Answer (score 3):

There's no `MiddleIndexOf` but both [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx) and [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3z4t9d.aspx) allow you to choose a point to start the search from.

For example:

```
string str = @"1\2\3\4\5";
//    indexes: 012345678
int index = str.IndexOf('\\', 4);
// index = 5, it starts searching from: "3\4\5"
```

To get the index of the second slash, this is what you'd do:

```
string str = @"1\2\3\4\5";
int index = str.IndexOf('\\', str.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

To get the second last slash, this is the code:

```
string str = @"1\2\3\4\5";
int index = str.LastIndexOf('\\', str.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1);
```

---

To list every index of a character inside of a string, these extension methods can help:

```
public static int[] GetAllIndexes(this string @this, string substr)
{
    var indexes = new List<int>();
    int index = -1;
    while ((index = @this.IndexOf('\\', index + 1)) >= 0) indexes.Add(index);
    return indexes.ToArray();
}
public static int[] GetAllIndexes(this string @this, char substr)
{
    var indexes = new List<int>();
    int index = -1;
    while ((index = @this.IndexOf('\\', index + 1)) >= 0) indexes.Add(index);
    return indexes.ToArray();
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
string str = @"1\2\3\4\5";
int[] indexes = str.GetAllIndexes('\\');
```

---

The `BeforeLastIndexOf` function you described could look like this:

```
public static int BeforeLastIndexOf(this string @this, string substr, int beforeCount)
{
    int index = @this.LastIndexOf(substr, @this.Length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < beforeCount && index >= 0; i++)
        index = @this.LastIndexOf(substr, index - 1);
    return index;
}
public static int BeforeLastIndexOf(this string @this, char substr, int beforeCount)
{
    int index = @this.LastIndexOf(substr, @this.Length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < beforeCount && index >= 0; i++)
        index = @this.LastIndexOf(substr, index - 1);
    return index;
}
```

You'd use it like:

```
string str = @"1\2\3\4\5";
//    indexes: 0123456789
int index = str.BeforeLastIndexOf('\\', 2);
```

It'd return 2 indexes before the last one. In this case it'd return 3. (\5 is the last one then \4 then \3, the index of the \ before \3 is 3).

---

You can do the same with `IndexOf` and make an `AfterIndexOf`:

```
public static int AfterIndexOf(this string @this, string substr, int afterCount)
{
    int index = @this.IndexOf(substr);
    for (int i = 0; i < afterCount && index >= 0; i++)
        index = @this.IndexOf(substr, index + 1);
    return index;
}
public static int AfterIndexOf(this string @this, char substr, int afterCount)
{
    int index = @this.IndexOf(substr);
    for (int i = 0; i < afterCount && index >= 0; i++)
        index = @this.IndexOf(substr, index + 1);
    return index;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
string str = @"1\2\3\4\5";
//    indexes: 0123456789
int index = str.AfterIndexOf('\\', 2);
```

This in turn returns 5, the \ before 4.

---

To really get the MiddleIndexOf, or with other words, the index closest to the middle, you can use this extension method:

```
public static int MiddleIndexOf(this string @this, string substr, bool roundUp = false, bool preferUp = true)
{
    // Determine the middle character
    int middlePoint = (roundUp ? @this.Length : @this.Length - 1) / 2;

    // Find the indexes closest to the middle
    int indexBelow = @this.LastIndexOf(substr, middlePoint);
    int indexAbove = @this.IndexOf(substr, middlePoint);
    if (indexBelow < 0) return indexAbove;
    if (indexAbove < 0) return indexBelow;

    int diffBelow = middlePoint - indexBelow;
    int diffAbove = indexAbove - middlePoint;

    return diffAbove == diffBelow ? (preferUp ? indexAbove : indexBelow) : // If it's the same difference
        (diffAbove < diffBelow ? indexAbove : indexBelow); // Otherwise return the closest index
}
public static int MiddleIndexOf(this string @this, char substr, bool roundUp = false, bool preferUp = true)
{
    // Determine the middle character
    int middlePoint = (roundUp ? @this.Length : @this.Length - 1) / 2;

    // Find the indexes closest to the middle
    int indexBelow = @this.LastIndexOf(substr, middlePoint);
    int indexAbove = @this.IndexOf(substr, middlePoint);
    if (indexBelow < 0) return indexAbove;
    if (indexAbove < 0) return indexBelow;

    int diffBelow = middlePoint - indexBelow;
    int diffAbove = indexAbove - middlePoint;

    return diffAbove == diffBelow ? (preferUp ? indexAbove : indexBelow) : // If it's the same difference
        (diffAbove < diffBelow ? indexAbove : indexBelow); // Otherwise return the closest index
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
string str = @"1\2\3\4\5\";
int index = str.MiddleIndexOf('\\');
```

There's two optional parameters:

- `roundUp`: If it's set to true, and you have an even amount of characters, it'll round up, otherwise it'd round down. For example, if you have 8 characters: `"12345678"` it'll choose `4` as middlepoint if roundUp is false, otherwise `5`.
- `preferUp`: When there's a character just as many characters away from the middlepoint later in the string as earlier in the string this'll determine which one it chooses. By default it is set to `true` to compensate for rounding down. (If you have a string of 8 characters `"\1\2\3\4"` the middlepoint should be at 3.5, but because this isn't possible it'll search from index 3. Index 3 is `'2'` a `\` is just as far away below as above. But due to this being true, it'll choose the character at index 4 which is 0.5 far away from the middlepoint, otherwise it'd choose index below, which would be `1.5` far away from the real middlepoint.)

Comment: I know there is no MiddleIndexOf, I just want to make it so. IF you know what I mean. Lets say I want to get the part of string "before last" so how to do it?

Comment: It's all there :). If you want third to last slash it'd be: `int index = str.LastIndexOf('\\', str.LastIndexOf('\\', str.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1) - 1);`

Comment: Hmm, what I case if I dont know the length of the chars between backslashes?

Comment: That doesn't matter at all, whether the string is `@"1\2\3\4\5"` or `@"123\45\6\789\89\10"` it just looks at the amount of \es

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a starting point to [`String.IndexOf(string, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx).  If the resulting index is beyond your "end point", there is nothing existing in between.

For example, given your string:

```
string str = @"1\2\3\4\5";
```

If you wanted to limit to `@"4\5"` and find the index of the slash:

```
int index = str.IndexOf(@"\", 6); // Start at char 6, returns 7
```

Comment: How about in case if I dont know the number of chars between backslashes?

Comment: @MitjaBonca In that case, use `IndexOf` to get the position of the *next* backslash, which gives you the end point.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the first character, you can use `string.IndexOf(value, startIndex)` to start searching for the next instance after the first.

This code will get the index of the second character:

```
public int static SecondIndexOf(this string str, char value)
{
    var firstIndex = str.IndexOf(char);
    if (firstIndex == -1)
        return firstIndex;

    return str.IndexOf(char, firstIndex + 1);
}
```